# matrix dimensions wont agree when elements match/matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having a problem at the final calculation of my code, the very last part, where log is the natural log, I need RD=facs.*log(log(facs))  to divide sigmafac, or robin=sigmafac./RD. My RD goes from 1 to 100, so does my sigmafac. why is there a matrix dimension mismatch?

I want the corresponding number (numbas) of RD to divide the correspoding number of sigmafac, the all have the same dimension, so I do not see where the problem is coming from. I realize that RD(1)=-inf, is that is what causing the problem? and how do I fix it?

code:

```
n=100;
primlist=2; % starting the prime number list


for numba=1:n;
   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0
      primlist=[primlist;2+numba]; %generating the prime number list
   end
end

fac=1; %initializing the factorials
RD=0;

for numbas=2:n

    %preallocating vectors for later use
    prims=zeros(size(primlist));
    pprims=zeros(size(primlist));
    pow=prims;

    for i=1:length(primlist) % identifying each primes in the primlist
        for k=1:10
            if mod(numbas,primlist(i).^k)==0
                prims(i)=primlist(i); % sum of all the powers of prims, such that prims divide numbas
                pow(i)=k; % collecting the exponents of primes
            end
        end

    if primlist(i)<=numbas
       pprims(i)=primlist(i); % primes less than or equal to numbas
    end

    end 


   % converting column vectors to row vector  
   PPRIMS=pprims';
   PRIMS=prims';
   POW=pow';


   %Creating the vectors
   PLN(numbas,:)=PPRIMS; % vector of primes less than or equal to number

   PPV(numbas,:)=PRIMS; % prime divisor vector

   PVE(numbas,:)=POW; % highest power of each primes for every number

   RVE=cumsum(PVE); % the cummulative sum of the exponents

   RVE(RVE~=0)=RVE(RVE~=0)+1; %selects each non zero element then add 1


   %factorial
   fac=fac*numbas;
   facs(numbas)=fac; %storing the factorials

   if facs==1
    RD==1; % log(log(facs1))) does not exist
   else RD=facs.*log(log(facs));
   end




end                


% setting up sum of divisor vector
NV=PLN.^RVE-1; % numerator part of sum of divisors vector
DV=PLN-1; % denominator part of sum of divisors

NV(NV==0)=1; % getting rid of 0 for elementwise product
DV(DV==-1)=1; % getting rid of -1 for elementwise product


sigmafac=prod(NV,2)./prod(DV,2); %sum of divisors


robin=(sigmafac)./(RD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sigmafac is `100x1` but your RD is `1x100` which is producing the error. If you want this to work just change

```
robin=(sigmafac)./(RD)
```

to

```
robin=(sigmafac)'./(RD)
```

This will make sigmafac a 1x100 (transpose) and then your vectors will have the same dimension and you will be able to do the division.

Comment: I dont know how much I can thank you, I really appreciate it! thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get such an error, your first check should be to test

```
size(sigmafac)
size(RD)
```

In this case, you'll get

```
ans =
   100     1
ans =
     1   100
```

So they are NOT the same size. You need to take the transpose of one or the other and then your division will work fine.